# WooCommerce login not working for some users with no errors

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, session, woocommerce

Our website has a login issue for some users. They don't see any errors at all and not log in. I changed a customer password and test it myself. No errors appeared and the user not logged in.

I delete user sessions but it doesn't work. So I really confused about that because we have this issue just with some users not all of them.

Do you have any ideas to test and figure out the bug?

Edited:
I figure out the user's logged_in_cookie has been set. It seems the username and password are working, cookies and sessions worked properly but user couldn't see my-account page or wp-admin. And there is no error there.

See the image please:
[image]

***Website Config:***

WP Version: 5.3.2

WC Version: 3.9.3

Server Info: nginx/1.17.5

PHP Version: 7.4.2

PHP Post Max Size: 128 MB

PHP Time Limit: 300

PHP Max Input Vars: 10000

Comment: First rule: update plugins to there latest version. Does WooCommerce 4.0.1 fix the issue?

Comment: @7uc1f3r Thanks for your answer. But the WooCommerce 4.0.1 released nowadays and maybe it has some bugs. We wait to release a stable version to update. Because we have huge ads champaigns these days and updating to WooCommerce 4.0.1 is risky for now.

Comment: @7uc1f3r I update to the WooCommerce 4.0.1 in our staging website but the problem still exists :(

Comment: Get more info from the affected users, what devices/browser/settings they use. Or fiddle with settings (probably mainly regarding cookie handling) on your own machine, and see if you can reproduce the error.

Comment: @CBroe I think the problem is not with the device or browser. Because I changed a customer password in the dashboard, and then try to log in in my-account page. When I enter the wrong password, the error 'Password is incorrect' appears. But when I entered the changed password (Right password) no errors appears and login not works.

Comment: I changed my theme to a default popular theme and not working again... I'll try to disable plugins. I think the problem is with sessions or cookies. But I don't know what is the best way to resolve the problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread that, and though you _could_ login as that user, on your machine, after changing the passwort. But if it doesn’t work there either, then a problem with session or cookies is rather unlikely though - that should affect all users the same, if you test on the same machine with the same browser settings. I’d try debugging into the login process in a local installation of the system, and check where exactly things start going wrong then.

Comment: I disabled all plugins except WooCommerce. I changed our theme to Twenty Twenty (WordPress default) and still, the problem exists. I changed the user password and it changed successfully because when I enter the wrong password, I got 'wrong password' error. But I couldn't log in with that user because no errors appeared.

Comment: I added an image, please check it out and if you know what is the problem I'll appreciate you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.
We using PHP version 7.4

When I changed it to 7.3, everything works like a charm :)

Resource: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/login-for-some-special-customers-not-possible/